# In what ways can the presidium of a meeting be elected?

Tags: combinatorics

The meeting of the Student Scientific Society was attended by $52$ students: with $13$ students each from $4$ faculties. In how many ways can four people be elected to the presidium of a meeting so that it includes students from $3$ faculties?

Attempt:  $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 13 \cdot 13 \cdot \dfrac{13 \cdot 12}{2!}$

Comment: First see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).  mathSE protocol requires the OP to edit his query to show work.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: 4*3*13*13*(13*12)/2!,

Comment: Pl put whatever you have tried in the *body* of your question.

Comment: Did you mean that four people are elected to the presidium?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes

Comment: In that case, the answer you wrote in the comments is correct.  It works out to $158,184$, not $518,184$, as you wrote in the comments below 10th grader's answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig how to solve this with formulas?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

For exactly three faculties to be represented in the presidium, two students must be elected from one of the four faculties and one student each must be elected from two of the remaining three faculties.

Choose which of the four faculties will have two representatives on the presidium, which two of the thirteen members of that faculty will be elected, which two of the remaining three faculties will have one representative each on the presidium, and which of the $13$ students in each of those faculties will be elected.  The number of ways the four members of the presidium can be elected so that the presidium includes students from exactly three of the four faculties is
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{13}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}$$
as you found.

Answer (score 0):

To find the four candidates, three of the four spots are fixed because you need at least 3 faculties. Each of these three spots can be occupied by 13 different students. The last spot can be a repeat or a different faculty. These two cases will be added.
Case 1: The fourth spot is occupied by the last faculty, there are 13 options
Case 2: The fourth spot is occupied NOT by the last faculty, there are 36 options

So now you have (13 * 13 * 13 * 13)+(13 * 13 * 13 * 36)=28,561+79,092=107,653

Now I think the question wants one of these candidates to be the presidium?
So you would do 107,653 choose 1 which is still 107,653

(The question is a little unclear to me)

Comment: answer is 518184

Comment: Oh dang. Can you please explain?

Comment: Mathematics StackExchange supports Math formatting so you can represent equations with ease. [$\mathbb{H}\text{ere is a }\mathcal{TUTORIAL}$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The spots on the presidium are not fixed.  The idea is that one of the four faculties must have two representatives on the presidium while two of the other three faculties must have one representative each on the presidium.

Comment: There are four faculties.  However, only three of them are represented on the presidium, which is why faculty has two representatives and two of the other three faculties have one representative each.

Comment: When the question says the 4 elected people must include students from 3 faculties, doesn't that mean there could be 1 student from each faculty?